# How can I measure dependency construction times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, profiling, autofac

I'm working with an open source ecommerce system written using C# and ASP.NET MVC 5. This package makes heavy use of autofac and IoC. It presents a plugin architecture that developers who work with this ecommerce package can use to create plugins, and it uses that plugin architecture itself.

Under some very mysterious circumstances (not just when the application domain recycles) it's taking a full minute to perform a page load. I've been struggling for a while to figure what's taking so long.

I haven't been able to get the application to run from within Visual Studio using the built in web server, and I haven't even been able to get the Visual Studio debugger to attach to an IIS process that is running it. So I haven't been able to use profilers that require Visual Studio.

I have managed to get Glimpse working, but Glimpse is not capturing the event that is taking a long time. In the time line, it shows "Start Request", which takes 0 ms, and then 7 to 50 seconds later, the next event starts, which is, for example, "Authorization: Home.Index", which it says took .01 ms.

What in the world is going on during that 7 to 50 second interval in between? How can I find that out?

Here's a somewhat strange clue: Today, after no change that we're aware of at all, suddenly the problem has more-or-less vanished (most of the time, at least temporarily) when the browser is on our internal network, but when the browser is on a computer outside our network, the problem persists. It's as if some plugin is doing some kind of DNS look up that is taking much less time (to succeed or fail) internally than it takes externally.

So conceivably, a controller is getting instantiated and some dependency or another from some plugin or another is doing some kind of network look up at construction time or something like that. So I'm trying to figure out how to measure how long it's taking MVC to construct each of the dependencies of the Home controller. So far, the solution has elluded me.

I guess I can maybe track down all the implementations of each of the dependencies and figure out which implementation is ending up getting used, and put log messages into their constructor code. Except some of the plugins don't provide source code. At least I can do it for the ones that do, anyway, but is there some profiler or tool I can use that doesn't require Visual Studio and works with ASP.NET MVC processes running under IIS?

Comment: How deep do your injections go, and how many methods do you have in each of your classes? We had an issue with classes that had had many injected dependencies, each of which had several injected dependencies, and Unity was constructing all of those dependencies--all the way down--even for methods that weren't being called on the current request. One solution was to use lazy construction via injecting `Func`s or `Lazy`s rather than the interfaces themselves. The better solution, though, is probably to refactor the class.

Comment: Perhaps ou could let us know which eCommerce platform you are using, that might help diagnose the issue. Particularly if the problem is from within the plaform and not your code.

Comment: Don't do any logging in your constructors. If you need that, it means that you are already doing _way too much_ in your constructors. Your injection constructors should do no more than check for null and store incoming dependencies. Anything that takes time should be moved out of your component's constructors. Read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) for more information.

Comment: Its NopCommerce. They're not "my" constructors, unfortunately - they're part of the platform. The list of injected parameters for a given controller is pretty long. I'm just trying to figure out which one, if any, is taking so long to be constructed.

Comment: NopCommerce isn't particularly heavy with it's constructors, so if it's taking a long time then it must be one of your own classes.

Comment: I've already logged out timings of my stuff, nothing I'm doing is involved in any of this slowness. It's weird, because it's sporadic. Sometimes it takes 1 second, other times it takes 60. It seems like it has to be some kind of networking issue. DNS trouble or something. Well, I changed some application domain settings and took Glimpse out, since it's not helping me, and now it's only slow for the first request of a page after that page hasn't been hit in a while.